# Moq returns values based on arguments

Tags: .net-core, moq

need small help about returning values based on arguments.
Setup of mocking contains expressions like

```cs
mockingObject
  .Setup(_=>_.Select(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>(),
                        It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>>(),
                        It.IsAny<List<Expression<Func<Entity, object>>>>(), It.IsAny<int?>(), It.IsAny<int?>())))
  .ReturnsAsync((Expression<Func<Entity,bool>>,Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>,List<Expression<Func<Entity,object>>>,int, int,EntityList());
```

But I'm getting error that `Expression<Func<Entity,bool>>` is a type which is not valid give context.
How should I manage `Returns`?

Need to mock:

```cs
public async Task<Result> UpdateNetworkStatus(string id, NetworkStatus status)
{
    var network = _unitOfWork.NetworkRepository.SelectListAsync(x => x.Id == id).Result.FirstOrDefault();
    if (network == null)
        throw new Exception(nameof(network));
    network.Status = status;
    _unitOfWork.NetworkRepository.Update(network);
    var saved = await _unitOfWork.Commit();
    if (!saved)
        return Result.Failure(new List<string>
        {
            "Failed to save"
        });
    return Result.Success();
}
```

Here I need to mock all possible scenarios.

Comment: Can you please share with us what do you want to mock?

Comment: First of all try not to mix blocking and non-blocking async calls. So prefer `await` over `.Result`

Comment: Secondly if you wish to mock EF Core then please one of these packages: [EntityFrameworkCore3Mock](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core3-mock), [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how I had manage to pass args to returns

```
   unitOfWorkMock.Setup(_ => _.EntityRepository.SelectListAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>(),
                It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>>>(),
                It.IsAny<List<Expression<Func<Entity, object>>>>(), It.IsAny<int?>(), It.IsAny<int?>()))
            .ReturnsAsync((Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> filter, Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IOrderedQueryable<Entity>> orderBy, List<Expression<Func<Entity, object>>> includes, int? page, int? pageSize) =>
            {
                if (filter == null)
                    return Entities();
                return Entities().AsQueryable().Where(filter).ToList();
            });
```